# Comments box in SharePoint server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

please i need to know if there is a solution to add a comments box in SharePoint server 2019 in order to add comments likes and displaying all comments for a news to different users I'm bloqued

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/679100/comments-box-in-sharepoint-server-2019.html), you want to add comments feature used in modern page to classic page, right?

Per my test and research, currently there is no such solution to meet your requirement, I also try to add the out of the box "Note Board" web part under the "Social Collaboration" section, however in SharePoint server 2019 wiki page, it shows blank.

So we recommend that you use modern pages, which include comment functions by default.

Comment: Hello @Julie_MSFT , In my case i use SharePoint server 2019 classic so i can't add a modern page for this version otherwise if you have a suggestion in this way i'll be grateful